# reasoning for set behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11

In one of our university projects we are working on a benchmarking project.
What we essentially do is generate a random no. and then insert it into a std::set (RBTree) and then delete it. We do this for a specific time interval. Essentially this is what the code looks like

```
auto randomNo = std::random_device{}();

//Measure insertion
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
myset.insert(randomNo ); //log(n)
auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto difference = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();
//record the diff.

//Measure erasures
start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
myset.erase(randomNum); //log(n)
end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
difference = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();
//record the diff.
```

Any idea why in some fresh runs insertion and deletion takes way more time than normal ?

Comment: I assume the reason is you always start with an empty set. If you do that, it could lead to several impacts, including but not limited to, cache behavior, rebalance cost, etc. Consider two phase in your benchmark: (i) data loading, where you will initialize (warmup phase) the set with some random data, (ii) actual benchmark, where you will perform a predefined number of insert/erase operation. This is well known technique for performing benchmark on data-structures.

Comment: The clocks in `std::chrono` measure wall time, not cpu time. There are a bunch of OS-level things that can take processor cycles away from your program.

Comment: Note that there is no requirement for `std::set()` to use a red-black tree under the hood, it's just the most common way to implement it.

Comment: What is "way more time than normal"?  Note that these C++ clocks have no specified precision.  Just because you cast to nanoseconds doesn't mean you're getting measurements at nanosecond precison ...  that alone can account for large differences run-to-run.  You could provide us some times - perhaps a little histogram (table) showing the discrepancy you find.

Comment: Also, why is your random number generation _inside_ your timing block?  You have no idea how long that takes, or if it is even uniform.  Oh wait, this isn't the code you're actually timing ...  Also, you don't know whether or not the items you're erasing are in the tree or not (which obviously gives different times)!  Oh wait, this isn't the code you're actually timing ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things that go wrong here:

- You only measure one insertion or erasure. You should try to measure how long it takes to perform a hundred thousand entries and take the average.
- You don't perform any warm-up. The set operation might operate with a cold CPU cache, the next memory allocation might not be satisfiable without the standard library needing to request a block of memory from the operating system, and so on. Try running a loop that does an operation on a hundred thousand iterations before you start the actual measurement.
- Your process might not run uninterrupted. There are many processes running on your computer, it could be that the operating system decides to pause your process for a while, giving another process a chance to run. If this happens between recording the `start` and `stop`, it will look like your operation took a long time.
- Most CPUs nowadays are changing the frequency at which they run all the time, in order to be power efficient and to stay cool. It could be that in some runs, the CPU frequency was different than in others. Having a warm-up phase and averaging many operations will help mitigate this effect.

I suggest you start using an existing benchmarking library to perform this kind of performance tests, like for example [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark). Often these libraries already solve some of these issues for you.

Comment: You can pin the process to a specific CPU to avoid the switching impact.

Comment: OP should consider using a properly designed _micro benchmark library_ to conduct these timings - after reading about how to do micro benchmarks.  One library - among several - that has been mentioned on SO in the past is [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually we do perform a warm up and insert a specific no. of elements into the set.

Comment: [YCSB-C](https://github.com/basicthinker/YCSB-C) is another good platform to do such benchmarking.

Comment: @Rajeshwar - so the code you posted isn't actually the code you're using?  As you know, that's suboptimal for getting focused correct SO answers.  I understand the need here on SO to post simple code ... but this is a bit misleading and could have been explained in your question.

Comment: @biqarboy It looks like YCSB specializes in benchmarking database applications, can it be used for generic C/C++ code that does not use a database at all?

Comment: @G.Sliepen You are right. We actually transformed the YCSB-C code and make it specialized for benchmarking data-structures in [ycsb-storedsbench repo](https://github.com/DIR-LAB/ycsb-storedsbench).